# Windows 7 Control Panel is crashing

Tags: windows-7

I've never seen this before, but every time I attempt to open the control panel, explorer crashes. It's Windows 64 bit Pro, with Office, and Visual Studio. Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Can you check the event logs and dig out any errors listed around the time Explorer crashes?  It may give an indication as to exactly what process or file is causing it to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One suggestion is to head over to `C:\Windows\System32`, order the list of files by file type and test each control panel applet (ending in **.cpl**).

Run (double-click) each one in turn and see if one causes Explorer to crash.  If you find the culprit, you should be able to replace it from a working computer.

An alternate may be to perform a **system restore**, if you have a date in mind when you know the control panel opened without crashing.

Comment: You may as well just rename the *.cpl* file to *.cpl.bak* in case you are disabling hardware as an example. To avoid losing time going through each control panel file just look at your **eventvwr.msc /s** as soon as explorer crashes.

Comment: Great. After trying many online suggestions, this worked on Windows 10. Also @Alan comment was very helpful. Many **.cpl** don't do anything when **run** and changing the extension was very useful. In my case the culprit was `AutoUpdatePlugin.cpl`.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the System File Checker, with the following command:

```
SFC /SCANNOW
```

If that doesn't work it might be prudent to run a repair install.

Comment: yeah, no luck. i guess it's time for reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a virus of some sort (hopefully not). You can run it in safe mode and try to do a system restore. Otherwise, you can also do a clean install, but I would suggest backing up your data first.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

```
cd c:\windows\system32\ <br>
mkdr cpl <br>
move *.cpl cpl\ <br>
```